# Can't access variable when using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] in include() filepath

Tags: php, document-root

I'm calling a database config file at the top of my file. I need to access the variables within the db config file as I'm running queries that return a result, which I am then calling in the file.

So in my db_config.php file I have the following:

```
$area_query = "SELECT * FROM `locations` where `type` = 'area'";

mysqli_query($db, $area_query) or die('Error querying database.');

$area_result = mysqli_query($db, $area_query);

if (!$area_result) {
  printf("Error: %s\n", mysqli_error($con));
  exit();
}
```

Then in a file called locations.php I am looping through the result of the above using:

```
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($area_result))
            {
                echo "<li class='location-list-item'><a href='location/$row[name]'><span class='initial-letter'>".mb_substr($row['name'],0,1)."</span>".$row['name']." <i class=\"fa fa-chevron-circle-right\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a></li>";
            }
```

This works fine if I include the db_config file using the following:

```
include("config/db_config.php");
```

However if I use:

```
include($SERVER['DOCUMENT ROOT']."/config/db_config.php");
```

It finds the db_config.php as expected (as echoing something in db_config.php outputs when visiting locations.php file) but I can't access $area_result. I get the following error:

```
Notice
: Undefined variable: area_result
on line
28


Warning
: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null 
given in
locations.php
on line
28
```

I'm confused as to why using $SERVER['DOCUMENT ROOT'] prevents me from accessing the variable? I need to use $SERVER['DOCUMENT ROOT'] for file path reasons.

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo, but it's DOCUMENT_ROOT, an underscore instead of space.

Comment: And `$SERVER` should be `$_SERVER`, missing `_` here as well.

Comment: Was a typo, still have an issue. Will resubmit question, thanks.

Comment: Turns out I have to wait 90 mins. OK spelling properly makes it work, if I include db_config in my locations.php file. However I am actually including db_config in my header.php file. I am including header.php in my locations.php file. When doing this using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] prevents me accessing the variables within db_config, but allows me to echo stuff out in db_config. Guessing theres some scope issue going on. It works fine when not using $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .

Comment: Can you please show us the way in which all these directories are organized? Also, how are you including one file into another? I'm guessing path related issues here.

Comment: I have an includes folder which contains header.php. I have a config folder which contains db_config.php. location.php is at root level. In header.php I call db_config.php, and in locations.php I call header.php. This works if I use relative file paths. However if I use $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] I lose access to the variables ($area_result for example) within the locations.php file. If I echo something in db_config.php it outputs when calling locations.php. Thanks.